# Shopify - Use Custom Image in Cart - Variant Image Not an Option

Tags: javascript, shopify

In Shopify, I have a custom product where the product chosen consists of multiple layers of  elements (3 to be exact).  I've learned how to combine those canvases into one image and would like that image (js image object) to translate over to the cart page.  Is this possible?

If it is, can it still be stored correctly if it's in the cart and the user visits the site again later?

Note:  Can't use a variant image for this because it's a product when customized can end up with over 4k variations.

Comment: You can store the image as a field in cart.attributes and pull it out when required on the fly.

Comment: Thanks @HymnZ, I'm looking into it right now but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add the attribute to the product checkout form.  Would you mind providing an example of the code?  I've already figured out how to capture all of my canvas layers into one image object.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this to store custom information for a product in the cart - https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products

Make sure the image that you are generating can actually called by a URL

To show in the custom information in cart and order page you can follow this - https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/line_item